# Where does the zecher lechurban go in an apartment building?

Tags: halacha, beis-hamikdash, architecture-design, home-house, zekher-lchurban

(A *zecher lechurban* here refers to the part of a house that is intentionally left unfinished to commemorate the Temple's destruction.)

In an apartment building, does there have to be a *zecher lechurban* in each apartment, or can a space in the lobby exempt the dwelling spaces inside? Perhaps a spot in a single apartment suffices for the entire building?

I know that leaving a *zecher* is a mitzvah for the builder (or building), not the resident (i heard this in a shiur recently), so a person who buys a house without a spot does not have to remove a tile to make one. However, the case of an apartment building with several living spaces is not clear to me: Is the entire complex considered as one, or do we view each apartment separately?

Comment: Interesting. The wording of the SA סימן תקס - לעשות זכר לחרבן makes it seems like it could apply to the entire complex. http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_32.html#HtmpReportNum0011_L2 - BTW - the last sentence is only true if a non-Jew built it - see be'er heitev ibid ואם ידוע שנעשה ביד ישראל באיסור חייב לקלפו

Comment: I believe there is a view (not widely accepted) that every *room* should have one.

Comment: @Loewian Yet most accept that understanding of בית as regards Mezuzah.

Comment: @DoubleAA safek d'oraissa l'chumra?

Comment: The practice I have consistently observed in Israel in apartment buildings is that each person places a zecher in their own apartment. I have never seen a building, even in haredi neighborhoods, do a building-wide one.

Comment: http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/halacha/Volume_7_Issue_8.pdf